# why am i gettin this error

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, phusion-passenger

```
 * Restarting web server apache2
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 184.106.238.30 for ServerName
 ... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using    184.106.238.30 for ServerName
...done.
```

I am installing a rails application teambox with passenger here is my vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www/teambox/public
ServerName www.something.com
<Directory /var/www/teambox/public>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Options -MultiViews
</Directory>

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

RailsEnv production
</VirtualHost>
```

and in my local host file i have

```
184.106.238.30 something.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache tries to lookup the name defined in the `ServerName` directive.  In your case this is `ServerName www.something.com`.   If you added `www.something.com` to your hosts file it would stop complaining.

Comment: This isn't what I thought, but I'm so tired my brain is leaking out my ear, and I'd probably just be babbling about monkeys...Just to clarify your point: www.something.com is distinct from something.com, so if you have something.com in your hosts file, instead of www.something.com, that could be causing the problem.

Comment: i fixed my host file but i still get the error on the server  /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 184.106.238.30 for ServerName
 ... waiting .apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 184.106.238.30 for ServerName
   ...done.

Answer (score 0):

What I thought it was (and wicked tired so YMMV) was that Apache's virtual host directive was choking on *:80 with a ServerName declared; I had trouble with that once. Try putting www.something.com:80 in your VirtualHost line, and see if that works.